# What is this Orchid with Unusually Shaped Petals?

Tags: identification, flowers, orchids

I took a picture of this orchid at the Atlanta Botanical Garden last year in June. If there was a name plate for it, I didn't see it. It's mostly white, with a bit of purple-pink color, has very unusually shaped petals, and flowers grow in long, hanging clusters.

[image: K]

Does anyone know what kind of orchid this is (at least the genus)?

Comment: After digging around a bit, I found that it's actually quite similar in terms of pattern and overall arrangement to the [_Rhynchostylis retusa_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhynchostylis_retusa) but the petals in this specimen have a significantly different shape.

Comment: If you took the photo in botanical garden, you may be able to ask them. In UK (and on many other places) they do also identification. I find the tepals not so unusual for an orchid: various orchids simulate the form of insects, to attract them.